# How to prove that $\frac{1}{9}= \sum_{i = 1}^{ \infty } \frac{1}{10^i}$

Tags: proof-explanation

I am new here and I am eager to find out how to prove this:
$\frac{1}{9}= \sum_{i = 1}^{ \infty } \frac{1}{10^i}$
Is induction a method in order to prove that?
Even though, to my knowledge, induction only works for finite numbers.
I really want to know the answer.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why not just use the formula for a sum of a geometric series?

Comment: This is not a proof:
$$\frac9{10}+\frac9{100}+\frac9{1000}+\cdots=0.9+0.09+0.009+\cdots=0.999\cdots=1$$

Comment: I am sorry but I'm 14 and in the 8th grade.

Comment: It is a geometric series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula

Comment: I have a math theory which includes sums and I already have direct proof for a part of it.

Comment: @OpenHax Then why not posting your working?

Comment: I just want to understand how it would be proven for future work.

Comment: I don't know should I post my working?

Comment: I mean everyone can steal adapt and post in their own name.

Comment: Use LaTeX to write math on the internet

Comment: @OpenHax What are you referring to about stealing? This is a very well-known result that (as far as I know) dates back to the ancient Greeks.

Comment: Guys I am 14 and I never been taught geometric series or something of that sort. I figured out a interesting thing and I made some formulas which would predict the outcome. I already have direct proof for a part of my theory. But I just want to extend my knowledge. I am not a mathematician I usually do programming I just wanted to understand more. Thanks for those who intended to help.

Comment: T Bongers I am not talking about the formula that I wrote above.

Comment: "I mean everyone can steal adapt and post in their own name. ", no offense meant, but at that level almost everything is prior art and someone would need real lots of money to bribe the authorities for ignoring this fact.

Comment: I made another formula.

Comment: @OpenHax It's great that you applied yourself and found another formula. You should definitely keep doing that. However, at this level everything is already known, so either your formula is wrong or it's a known one. I encourage you to post it so that you can learn further.

Comment: rubik thanks for being so kind and honest to a newbie in mathematics like me

Comment: My formula it's not at this level for sure. It's more complex and more elegant and yes it is possible that it has been found by someone else but I searched and didn't find anything. I can't wait to show my work to you. I first want to 100% prove it. As I said, I already have some direct proof for a part of it and now I have to clear some things up and put it next to a nice formulation like a nice formula deserves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A=\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{1000}+...$

$10A=1+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{1000}+...$

$10A-A=1$

$A=\frac{1}{9}$

So the sum really equals $\frac{1}{9}$.

Comment: The beauty is in the simplicity +1

Comment: Thanks for explaining. As @daniels_pa said, the beauty is in the simplicity and I really appreciate that. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a proof. $1{+}2{+}4{+}\ldots=({-}1{+}2){+}({-}2{+}4){+}({-}4{+}8){+}\ldots={-}1{+}(2{-}2){+}(4{-}4){+}\ldots={-}1$

Comment: Then can you please provide proof?

Comment: I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: @OpenHax Nope. I think the accepted answer of the question which this is a duplicate of does explain it pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

There are much easier ways of doing this, but if you really want to use induction:

You can show the following finite case:

$\frac{1}{9}$ written out to $k$ decimal places is equal to $\sum_{i = 1}^k \frac{1}{10^i}$ for all $k \geq 1$

If you prove this, for the infinite case you know that this will be true for $k \rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 0):

$$S=\frac { 1 }{ { 10 }^{ 0 } } +\frac { 1 }{ { 10 }^{ 1 } } +\frac { 1 }{ { 10 }^{ 2 } } +\frac { 1 }{ { 10 }^{ 3 } } +\cdots \\ \frac { S }{ 10 } =\frac { 1 }{ { 10 }^{ 1 } } +\frac { 1 }{ { 10 }^{ 2 } } +\frac { 1 }{ { 10 }^{ 3 } } +\frac { 1 }{ { 10 }^{ 4 } } +\cdots =\sum _{ i=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ { 10 }^{ i } }  } \\ S-\frac { S }{ 10 } =\frac { 1 }{ { 10 }^{ 0 } } =1\\ \frac { 9S }{ 10 } =1\\ \frac { S }{ 10 } =\frac { 1 }{ 9 } $$